# GET Request with Content-Type and Accept header with JAX-RS Jersey 2.2

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs, content-type

I try to access an open data web service which gives me traffic infos. Documentation says that requests have to be `GET` and need to contain `Accept: application/json` and `Content-Type: application/json`. I don't understand why they need the `Content-Type` but ok:

I tried to retrieve data with just the `Accept:` Header but I'm always getting a `415 Unsupported Media Type`. Now I am currently trying it this way (but I'm not sure if I am really setting both headers correctly):

```
String entity = ClientBuilder.newClient().target(liveDataURI)
    .path(liveDataPath)
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .get(String.class);
```

As you see I am using Jersey 2.2 and I'm still getting a `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

**EDIT**

So I got it to work but I don't understand why. Isn't `accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` and `header("Content-type","application/json")` the same?

```
String responseEntity = ClientBuilder.newClient()
    .target(liveDataURI)
    .path(liveDataPath)
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .header("Content-type", "application/json")
    .get(String.class);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `Accept` header tells the server what your client wants *in the response*. The `Content-Type` header tells the server what the client sends *in the request*. So the two are *not* the same.

If the server only accepts `application/json`, you must send a request that specifies the request content:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

That's why your edited code works.

**Edit**

In your first code you use [`WebTarget.request(MediaType... acceptedResponseTypes)`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html#request%28javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType...%29). The parameters of this method

> define the accepted response media types.

You are using [`Innvocation.Builder.accept(MediaType... mediaTypes)`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html#accept%28javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType...%29) on the result of this method call. But `accept()` adds no new header, it is unnecessary in your first code.

You never specify the content type of your request. Since the server expects a `Content-Type` header, it responds with `415`.

Comment: Ooookay got it! But on a sidenote: Im not sending anything to the server, Im just doing the request, so why is the Content-type necessary anyway? Count the parameters I send as "content"?

Comment: What parameters? I have no idea why this server requires a `Content-Type` for a `GET`. You must ask the people who run this server :)

Comment: I can specify the request with some parameters in the URI. But anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: The Accept header in the request tells the server what your client wants in the response. The Content-Type header in response tells the client what server sent in the response to client. So the two are not the same.

Comment: In the request headers, `Accept` applies to the response body whereas `Content-Type` applies to the request body. See list of [HTTP request headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields)

Answer (score 18):

> Isn't `accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` and `header("Content-type","application/json")` the same?

No, they are different.
This is how they are related:

```
Client                     Server
(header)                   (class/method annotation)
====================================================
Accept          <--->      @Produces
Content-Type    <--->      @Consumes
```

The server consumes what it receives from the client in body (its format is specified in `Content-Type`) and it produces what the client accepts (its format is specified in `Accept`).

**Example**:

- **client** sends the following headers:

  - `Content-Type` = `text/xml` (it sends an XML in body)
  - `Accept` = `application/json` (it expects to get a JSON as a response)
- **server** needs to have at least the following annotations for the corresponding method (the annotations are taken from the class level, if they are not explicitly mentioned for that method):

  - `@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_XML)` (it gets an XML from the client)
  - `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` (it sends a JSON to the client)

**Obs**:

1. The server can be more flexible, being configured to get/produce **multiple** possible **formats**.

   E.g.: a client can send an XML while another client can send a JSON to the same method if it has the following annotation: `@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_XML })`.
2. The `MediaType` values are just `String` constants:

   ```
   public final static String APPLICATION_JSON = "application/json";
   public final static String TEXT_XML = "text/xml";
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ContainerResponseFilter` to set the default Accept header if it is not provided in the input request.

```
@Provider
public class EntityResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    private MediaType getExternalMediaType(){
        MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("application", "vnd.xxx.resource+json")
        return mediaType; 
    }

    @Override
    public void filter( ContainerRequestContext reqc , ContainerResponseContext resc ) throws IOException {
        MediaType mediaType = getExternalMediaType(); 
        List<MediaType> mediaTypes = reqc.getAcceptableMediaTypes();
        if( mediaTypes.contains(mediaType) ) {   
            resc.setEntity( resc.getEntity(), new Annotation[0], mediaType );
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```