# Error 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, jersey

I have some problem with making a good request.

```
@Path("/activitiesGenerator")
public class ActivityResource {

ActivityStub acstub = new ActivityStub();

@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Collection<Activity> getAllActivities(){

    return acstub.Find_All_Activities();
}


@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("{activityId}") // Will act as parameter that will take value from the browser!
public Response getActivity(@PathParam("activityId") String activityId){

    if(activityId.equals(null) || activityId.length() < 4){

        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }

    Activity activity  = acstub.FindActivity(activityId);

    if(activity.equals(null)){

        return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }

    return Response.ok().entity(activity).build();
}
```

From here I pass the value!

```
@Test
public void main() {

    ActivityClient client = new ActivityClient();

    Activity activity = client.get("3204987");

    System.out.println(activity);

    assertNotNull(activity);
}
```

Here I make the check of response..

```
public Activity get(String id){

    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/Activities/rest/");
    Response response = target.path("activitiesGenerator/"+id).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(Response.class);

    System.out.println(response.getStatus());

    if(response.getStatus() != 200){

        throw new RuntimeException(response.getStatus()+ ": there was an error on the server");
    }

    return response.readEntity(Activity.class);

}
```

I got an exception from get method. The response is 400 Bad request. 
  What did I make wrong?

Here is mine web.xml file!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>Activities</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ActiviteExample</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>activity.model</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ActiviteExample</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

 Could not get any response
 This seems to be like an error connecting to      http://HTTP://localhost:8080/Activities/rest/activities-generator/3204987.
 Why this might have happened:
 The server couldn't send a response:
 Ensure that the backend is working properly
 SSL connections are being blocked:
 Fix this by importing SSL certificates in Chrome
 Cookies not being sent:
```

Here is what I got from mine postman. I will appreciate if anybody can explain me more specific about this possible solutions...

Comment: Do you see any errors in the server log? Have you checked the response entity from the error to see if it has any useful information for debugging?

Comment: I got the 400 number from the response.. I printed the response number. 
I got 400 and as i know it some syntax error.. but i don't see any syntax error.. i will add the web.xml

Comment: do you have a pom.xml?

Comment: No. I don't use Maven.

Comment: have you tried accessing it with your browser?

Comment: also, does "3204987" exists in your application? try putting a print before you return bad request exception in getActivity

Comment: Well there is a print method int the code. 
What do you mean  - does "3204987" exists in your application?

Comment: I accessing it with mine browser..

Comment: in your example, you do `client.get("3204987");` which sends a request : `http://localhost:8080/Activities/rest/activitiesGenerator/3204987` . Have you tried this adress?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Activities/rest/activitiesGenerator/3204987
Yes. I get the same result..

Comment: Can't understand what syntax error could it be..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Accepts header to the client code. The Accepts header will tell the server that the client making the request is willing to take the particular Mime type. If you are expecting json, specify application/json.

`request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` will only tell that the data sent to the server is json. It does not tell what you are willing to accept.

Make the requests in browser and use some browser addons to set the headers and watch the responses.

Read more about the [Accept header here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595537/get-request-with-content-type-and-accept-header-with-jax-rs-jersey-2-2)

Comment: Well. I making the task with some tutorial from pluralsight..
I making the same as the guy there but have this kind of problem. 
What Accept header can you explain me ? 
In the tutorial the request was simple from the application with JUnit usage. Exactly the same as mine code..