# Accept-Encoding:gzip and Content-Encoding:gzip

Tags: http-headers, gzip, content-encoding

What is the difference between the two HTTP headers?

- Accept-Encoding:gzip
- Content-Encoding:gzip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GET Request with Content-Type and Accept header with JAX-RS Jersey 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595537/get-request-with-content-type-and-accept-header-with-jax-rs-jersey-2-2)

Comment: Please read [ask] and show your research. In short: `Accept-` headers tell the server what kind of responses the client wants.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Accept-Encoding:

It is a request header. The HTTP client uses this header to tell the server which encoding(s) it supports.  The server is allowed to send the response content in any of these encodings.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding)

> The Accept-Encoding request HTTP header advertises which content encoding, usually a compression algorithm, the client is able to understand. Using content negotiation, the server selects one of the proposals, uses it and informs the client of its choice with the Content-Encoding response header.

## Content-Encoding:

It is a response header. The HTTP server uses this header to tell the client which particular encoding the content has actually been encoded in.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding)

> The Content-Encoding entity header is used to compress the media-type. When present, its value indicates which encodings were applied to the entity-body. It lets the client know, how to decode in order to obtain the media-type referenced by the Content-Type header.

If you want to see them play in action, open `Inspect Element` in Firefox / Chrome, then check for the `Network` tab to see them in action. Look for `Accept-Encoding` in request headers and `Content-Encoding` in response headers.

[image: Inspect Element in firefox]

Answer (score 2):

**Accept-Encoding**

To paraphrase IETF internet standard RFC-7231, the Accept-Encoding request header field can be used by user agents to make requests that indicate what response content-codings are acceptable in the response.

The Accept-Encoding header can be quite complex, e.g.

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, identity; q=0.5, *;q=0
```

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-5.3.4

**Content-Encoding**

The Content-Encoding response header field indicates what content codings have been applied to the response representation. Content-Encoding is primarily used to allow the response entity to be compressed without losing the identity of   its underlying media type.

The Content-Encoding value is simple and should be accompanied by a "Vary" header, e.g.

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.2.2